# What is an alternative for os.startfile() for a mac user?

Tags: python, macos

I know mac users cannot use `os.startfile()` but is there any alternative for mac users?

I am just trying to load a file within python but I would like to find a way to do so.

Error:

```
 Module 'os' has no 'startfile' member
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: @LeoGaunt python 3.7

Comment: @dejdej Yes that did thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `os.system` with `open`. For example:

```
os.system("open Untitled.pdf")
```

This will open the file Untitled.pdf with the default PDF application ('Preview', in my case).

Comment: it's recommended to use subprocess over os.system...but it does work

Answer (score 1):

you should just be able to do:

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.call(['open', 'application_or_file_name'])
```